# SQL - Specifying relations yet still getting too many records?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm newer to SQL coding. I have 4 tables, and I want to group together Company names with route IDs. I am attempting to use/alter the code below, however I am getting way too many records back, and it is incorrectly mixing all of the company names with route ids.

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude, RouteName, CompanyName
FROM STOP 
INNER JOIN RouteStop 
ON Stop.Stop_ID = RouteStop.Stop_ID 
INNER JOIN Route
ON RouteStop.Route_ID = Route.Route_ID
INNER JOIN Company
ON Route.Company_ID = Company.Company_ID
WHERE RouteStop.Route_ID = 1
AND Company.Company_ID = 1
```

Here is a picture from SQLfiddle

[image]

[And a link to my SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47a8e/1)

I'm looking to only return 3 records back with this code, because Route 1 (`WHERE RouteStop.Route_ID = 1`) of the first Bus Company (`AND Company.Company_ID = 1`) should only have three stops.

I must have made an error when designing my database, as Route 1 of Company 1 is suppose to have 3 records, and Route 1 of Company 2 is suppose to have 10 records. However with my SQL code, I am getting 13 records instead of 3 for company 1.

When filling up my Route table, I used this code right here:

```
INSERT INTO `Route` (`Route_ID`, `Company_ID`, `RouteNum`, `RouteName`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'Corning Community College'),
(2, 1, 2, 'East Corning and Gibson'),
(3, 1, 3, 'Northside'),
(4, 1, 4, 'Southside'),
(5, 1, 5, 'Coopers Plains, Gang Mills, and Painted Post'),
(6, 2, 1, 'Elmira to Corning'),
(7, 2, 2, 'Southtown route'),
(8, 2, 3, 'St. Joe’s Loop'),
(9, 2, 4, 'Bulkhead'),
(10, 2, 5, 'Arnot Loop'),
(11, 2, 6, 'Golden Glow Drive'),
(12, 2, 7, 'Lake Road'),
(13, 2, 8, 'Shopper Shuttle');
```

Which I thought could divide different unique stops and routes by a Company_ID...Does anyone possibly have a solution to my issue?? Thanks for all and any help!

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with the SQL. Maybe provide a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Okay I'll do that now

Comment: The distinct keyword will get you started.  Deleting the latitude and longitude is the next step.  If you really need those values as well, use your php to group the query results.

Comment: Yep, `distinct` is definitely helping me in this situation, thanks Dan! Yes, my goal is to get the multiple `Latitude` and `Longitude` records where `Route_ID = 1` (or any number) and `Company_ID = 1` (or any number). Do you possibly have any advice to spare on achieving this goal??

Comment: I know how to do it with ColdFusion.  I added a php tag to get more php programmers to see your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This sql looks correct to me.

Company Id 1 ("CEATS") has a record in the Route table for Route ID 1 ("Corning Community College").

Route 1 has 13 records in the RouteStop table.

What you are getting is the Latitude and Longitude from the Stop table, linking that to the RouteStop table by id for stops in Route 1, linking that Route Stop to the Route table on Route 1 so you can display the Route Name, and linking the Route table to the company table by the Company table for id 1 and displaying the Company Name.

There are 13 records being returned because there are 13 stops in Route ID 1 and Company ID 1.

One thing I do notice is that stops 47 & 50 and stops 48 & 49 have the same longitude and latitude (and stop names).  So, that leads to the question of whether this is bad data.  There are two records in the Stop table for Corning Community College and Corning-Transportation Center.

Adding DISTINCT, as stated in the comments to the question, will limit the returned data, but it appears there is some duplicated data in the Stop table.

In fact, running this sql will show there are 5 duplicate records in the stop table:

```
SELECT stopname, count(*)
from stop
group by stopname
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for your response!! Hmmm, I must've done something incorrect when designing my tables and relations, because Route 1 of Company 1 is suppose to have 3 records, and Route 1 of Company 2 is suppose to have 10 records. I will edit my question to point out the code where I must have made a design error